# WordPress Custom Image Slider to use pages not posts?

Tags: wordpress

I normally create a custom image slider using Featured Images from posts, sometimes in a certain category or from a custom post type.
Is there a way I can do this but to display pages, not posts?

How would I be able to select which pages are shown in the image slider and what code would I need to retrieve all the meta from that page? Featured Image, Page Title and Excerpt and permalink?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use is_page() wordpress built-in function.

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page for details